# Set background colors of calendar cells in CodenameOne

Tags: calendar, codenameone, background-color

I would like to change the background color for several days at once in a CodenameOne calendar.

Is this possible? Does anyone maybe have a code example?

I imagine obtaining dates from a list or a hash table (like: 01-08-2017, 05-08-2017, 20-08-2017) and set a distinct background color for these days in the calendar.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@Override
protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentMonth, int day) {

        //Customize day values

        dayButton.setText("" + day);

        Style s = dayButton.getAllStyles();

        s.setPaddingTop(3);
        s.setPaddingBottom(3);
        s.setBgColor(ColorUtil.BLUE);
        s.setBgTransparency(255);

        //s.setBorder(null);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the `com.codename1.ui.Calendar` class. The trick for customizing that is to derive the class and override the `updateButtonDayDate` method where you can set the UIID for the specific selected day to anything you want.

Comment: With this approach, is it possible to select multiple dates? Would you happen to have a snippet? I am still quite new to programming and Java, and this is my first mobile app ever, and I am having difficulties to image how the solution would look like in practice.

Comment: I found a good example (updated above) to change the background color for the whole month. How would I go about accessing several individual dates? I couldn't find anything related on the net ..

Comment: You can set the day background by calling `setUIID()` check out the section about theming in the developer guide https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html where we explain how you can define UIID's. Ranges is a matter of your logic, if you have a range selected the update method can check if the current button is in the range and set the range UIID appropriately. It's not something trivial and I don't have an example of this exact feature around

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution :

To select or display multiple dates in a Codename Calendar, one option is adding the dates to a list and format the date buttons according to the list items :

```
 cal = new Calendar() {

        @Override
        protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentYear, int currentMonth, int day  ) {

            list.add(1);
            list.add(12);
            list.add(13);
            list.add(14);
            list.add(21);


            for (int day_Number : list) {

                if (day_Number == day) {

                    dayButton.setText("" + day);
                    dayButton.setUIID("mycalender-day");

                }

        }

    };
```

The css file contains the formatting style:

```
mycalender-day {

border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
color:orange;
font-family:  "native:MainRegular";
font-size: 7pt;
}
```